# How to show a function is Lebesgue/Borel measurable

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I need to show whether the function f is Borel measurable or not and also if it is Lebesgue measurable or not. f is given by:
$$f(x) =
\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  2^n,  & \mbox{if } x=n\in\mathbb{Z} \\
  0, & \mbox{otherwise }
 \end{array}
\right.$$
But I don't know how to go about doing this. Any help at all would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you do it if we write "If $x \in \Bbb {Z} $ and $|x|\leq N $", where $N $ is fixed? Note that we are talking about a finite set.

Comment: It is continuous a.e. So $\mathbb{R}=A\cup B,$ where $A$ is null and $f$ is continuous on $B$. Hence, $f^{-1}(U)=f^{-1}(U)\cap A\cup f^{-1}(U)\cap B$. Is it enlightening?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Finite sums of measurable functions are measurable; and, pointwise limits of sequences of measurable functions are measurable.

If you follow @PhoemueX suggestion, can you write 
$$
f_N(x):=\begin{cases}2^n & \text{if $x=n\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $\lvert x\rvert\leq N$}\\0 & \text{else}\end{cases}
$$
as a finite sum of measurable functions?